# Bulk 301 Redirect for URLs with Query Strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my first post hoping somebody can help. I have found similar answers but nothing I try seems to work. I have recently redesigned a client website, their old site was OLD. IT has a lot of redirects needed and the site had a lot of query string URLs.

I need to 301 redirect in bulk all URLs which have the following in their URL:

```
/suppliersearch.php?start={Query String}
```

to

```
/wedding-directory
```

Everything I have tried has been ignored by the Redirect.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start= [NC]
RewriteRule suppliersearch\.php$ /wedding-directory/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

If it is Apache 2.4 or later; you can use `QSD` flag instead of the redirection to `..directory/?`.